# beginner tutorials to learn blender

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, rigging, bones

I am a beginner wanting to learn Blender. I have a few different versions of blender with the latest being 2.82A 
I would prefer to learn the recent blender but I have no problem learning one a version down from this. I prefer the recent version, as I would have to stumble my way thru where the new stuff is or not be aware of the new changes and get frustrated because I'm looking for something that no longer was needed with the older versions. Im especially interested in Second Life Body imports and exports and clothes modeling. My second choices would be making trees and plants and my last would be builds of any kind. My whole purpose, that interested me to learn blender was to make realistic looking clothing, as the Second Life Virtual Reality is changing and growing so fat, I would love to learn these things. 
thank in advance for any help I can find in doing so
Enchtris Byrd

Comment: Hello :). BlenderGuru's legendary Donut Tutorial is a [great place to start](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U)

Comment: ty so much Jachym, I will go check that out and try these. I appreciate the reply!

Comment: Happy to help :). There is also [a whole thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/78972) about resources for Blender, including learning. Good luck on your Blender journey :).

Comment: thank you again Jachym I do appreciate any help and the more resources the better, thanks! hugz